# Pul MySql Database values to liststore - Python3 and Mysql.connector

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x

Fairly new to python and looking for some assistance to make it bend to my will. I am working on a small application that will use a databse to populate various comboboxes that are all linked to various liststore objects. I am able to pull my data from MySQL but it all falls apart when trying to insert the values to the list store. I either end up:

```
ValueError: row sequence has the incorrect number of elements
```

My liststore object is configured for a single row gchararray

My code looks like this:

```
mysqldb = mysql.connector.connect(**mysql_config)
cnx = mysqldb.cursor()
cnx.execute("SHOW TABLES")

for (table_name, ) in cnx:
    dblist.append(''.join(table_name))

for i in range(len(dblist)):
    self.list_customers.append(list(dblist[i]))

cell = Gtk.CellRendererText()
self.combo_systems.pack_start(cell, False)
self.combo_systems.set_active(0)
```

As a sanity check if i insert:

```
dblist = [['1'], ['2'], ['3']]
```

right before

```
for i in range(len(dbslit)):
    self.list_customers.append(list(dblist[i]))
```

it works fine.

Comment: print `dblist` after your first `for` loop. Does it contain what you expect?

Comment: I should add that the output of for(table_name, )... is ('bar', 'foo', 'foobar')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will get the same format as `[['1'], ['2'], ['3']]`:

```
cnx = mysqldb.cursor()
cnx.execute("SHOW TABLES")

tables = cnx.fetchall()   #  [('table1',), ('table2',), ...]
self.list_customers = [list(rec) for rec in tables]
...
```

or just

```
self.list_customers = [list(rec) for rec in cnx.fetchall()]
```

although you might get away with simply

```
self.list_customers = cnx.fetchall()
```

if the gtx interface doesn't insist on lists of lists..

Comment: Thanks!!  I couldn't assign the values directly per `self.list_customers = [list(rec) for rec in tables]` but I could assign it to dblist and then iterate and append.  Very much appreciated!

Comment: in that case you can try `self.list_customers += [list(rec) ...`